# SQL join unexpected result

Tags: join, sql-server-2017

I have the following table:

| item | running | resourceid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 017510 | C1 | 43 |
| 338877 | C4 | 44 |
| 451233 | C1 | 45 |
| 771225 | C4 | 41 |
| 011212 | C4 | 47 |
| 313366 | C3 | 34 |
| 771226 | C4 | 48 |
| 990000 | C4 | 46 |

for each "running" I need to get the Max resourceid and it's item which give me the expected result:

| running | resourceid | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 45 | 451233 |
| C3 | 34 | 313366 |
| C4 | 48 | 771226 |

With this code:

```
SELECT
b.running,
MAX(b.resourceid)as MaxResourceid,
MAX(b.item) as item
FROM runningResources as b
inner join (SELECT 
    running,
    MAX(resourceid) as MaxValue
    FROM runningResources
    GROUP BY running ) a ON
    a.running=b.running and a.Maxvalue=b.resourceid
    group by b.running
```

Since the query

```
SELECT
b.running,
MAX(b.resourceid)as MaxResourceid,
MAX(b.item) as item
FROM runningResources as b
group by b.running
```

gives the result:

| running | resourceid | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 45 | 451233 |
| C3 | 34 | 313366 |
| C4 | 48 | **990000** |

why is C4 in the final result showing **771226**    ?
I would think that the join would give the item of the outer SELECT (C4,48,990000)

Comment: I suggest you try removing the MAX() and the GROUP BY from the external, main query.

Comment: ty, it does make more sense without the MAX() and the GROUP BY as you suggested.

Comment: You don't have a row with `C4,48,990000`. Your second query is grouping by `running` and getting the max of each of those columns - these maxes come from different rows. Your first query is just getting the max `resourceid` per `running` and then joining back on that to get the rest of the row.

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()` to find the row with the highest `resourceid`. And then filter it at the outer query

```
select running, resourceid, item
from   ( 
           select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by running 
                                                 order by resourceid desc)
           from   runningResources 
       ) as a
where  a.rn = 1
```